# Joins different tables to get expected results

Tags: sql, sql-server

2 books were taken by student 333 - physics and history.
Student subscribed to both books. However the student had optional package taken
for physics book. We need the records where student has taken both subscribed and optional books

I have the below code, however the Expected Records table is returning only Physics as ModuleID.
It is ignoring the History in the BooksSubsribed table. The end result should be both subscribed and optional books

*Note In table 1 (BookNo 2 PackageId is set to IrelandADV instead of NULL)

```
DECLARE @StudentId varchar(50)
SET @StudentId = '333'
```

[image]

```
SELECT ModuleId
    FROM Books AS B WITH (NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN BooksSubscribed AS BS WITH (NOLOCK) 
    ON B.ModuleId = BS.ModuleId 
    AND BS.StudentId = @StudentId
    INNER JOIN OptionalPackage OP WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON  B.ModuleId = OP.ModuleId
    AND B.PackageID = OP.PackageId
    AND OP.StudentId = BS.StudentId
```

The below 3 tables is returning the values as shown.
I want the final table to contain both the BooksSubscibed record and the Optional Package table record:

ModuleId
Physics
History

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Images of data don't help us help you. Take the time to post it in a consumable format; preferable DDL and DML statements, or if not well formatted tabular `text`.

Comment: Please describe what should be returned if a student has a certain package in `OptionalPackage` but not in `BooksSubscribed`; the current example does not cover this.

Answer (score 1):

Can optional package can have entry for any books where there is no entry for that book in books subscribed table? Your query will return only those modueid for which there is entry in both books subscribed table and optional package table. Try this:

```
 select distinct bst.ModulelD from BooksSubscribed bst inner join Books b on b.ModulelD=bst.ModulelD and StudentlD=333 
and b.PackagelD is null or PackagelD in (select PackagelD from OptionalPackage where StudentlD =333)
```

Comment: This returns only the Physics record not history one

Comment: Currecting the answer. It should return physics and history if there is entry in optionpackage table for physics other wise it should return physics only. right?

Comment: I have edited my answer. It's working properly now.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it's working correctly now

Answer (score 0):

The reason for History being ignored in the output is because you have used `INNER JOIN` for the `OptionalPackage` table.  `INNER JOIN` will only produce a row if a match is present in both tables.

Changing this to a `LEFT JOIN` will include all results with and without Optional Packages.